# in excel, I want to count the number of cells that do not contain a specific character

Tags: excel

in excel, I want to count the number of cells that do not contain a specific character (in this case, a "." /period).

I tried something like countif(A1:A10,"<>.*") but this is wrong and I can't seem to figure it out.

Say I have these data in column A:

```
D
N
P
.
.
A
N
.
P
.
```

And the count would be 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>.")
```

returns `6`. But it would be a different story if say you wanted to exclude `P.` from the count also.

Your data may not be quite what you think it is however, because including the `*` should make no difference for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could subtract periods from the total and be left with the non periods

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*")-COUNTIF(A1:A10,"=.")
```

gives 6.

Comment: yeah assuming you know the count of the range, which you do here but you might not in general

Answer (score 1):

If your data includes periods along with other characters in the same cell and want a similar count:

[image]

then this:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A10)-COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*.*")
```

will return **5**