# EXCEL - SUM all tiles that do not contain a specific character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My cell network operator has sent me an excel spreadsheet with all my data usage and phone calls for the month.

I would like to calculate the data usage, but the problem is that the phone call durations are in the same column and i would like to exclude them.

The call durations are seperated by ":" (HH:MM:SS) and the data usage has no seperators. I would like to do a "=SUMIF" that excludes any column that contains ":"

```
12159
6
5
5
1
9
5
00:00:45
00:00:06
00:00:25
00:00:03
4783
00:00:38
00:00:03
66678
1
8
3
00:00:29
00:00:01
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:57
147716
5
93
1
```

I have tried [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559410/in-excel-i-want-to-count-the-number-of-cells-that-do-not-contain-a-specific-cha) with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as time is a decimal value of less than 1:

```
=SUMIF(F:F,">=1")
```

This method does assume that your calls are not longer than 24 hours.

[image]

Comment: @NevinConstantin please come back in a few minutes and mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is available after the question is 15 minutes old.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`=SUMIF(F1:F10;">1";F1:F11)`
If you haven't made a call with a duration of more than 24 hours, it will work :)

Comment: 1. why the duplicate of mine? 2. you want `">=1"` or it will miss 3 in the test data provided.  3.  The third criterion is optional only if the range that is being summed is different than the range for which we are filtering, and in this case they are the same so it is not needed.

Comment: 1. I'm sorry I hadn't seen your answer. 2. You're right. 3. I just tried to keep the format the "Excel Formula Assistant" uses, but yours is of course more elegant and optimized.